# Having issues with gravity and linear layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I've used this site a lot the past 6 months since I've started android developing and haven't had to ask a question yet but now I've run into an issue that's driving me nuts that I cannot figure out.

Basically what I'm trying to do is `HORIZONTALLY` create a `GridView` that takes up roughly 4/10ths of the screen with a vertical LinearLayout 2/10ths that contains some buttons followed lastly by a scrollview that will take up roughly 4/10ths of the screen as well.

GridView 4/10th Middle LinearLayout 2/10th scrollview 4/10th

My issue though is that the layouts are not being displayed correctly. My GridView will take up half of my screen same with my scrollview and my middle layout will be gone.

Or

Gridview takes up only(visually speaking 80px roughly), my middle `LinearLayout` will take up almost all of the screen and my scrollview will take up roughly a third.

I've missed around quite a bit with gravity and other things in my xml file but to no success.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activity_Test"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp" 
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" >


    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/image_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:numColumns="@integer/num_columns"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dip"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dip"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_weight=".4"
        android:background="@color/grid_background"  />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/middle"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/home"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/battle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/begin"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".3">


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/test_bt_pick_pilot"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/test_bt_pick_pilot"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/test_bt_pick_pilot"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/test_bt_pick_pilot"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/test_bt_pick_pilot"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks a lot guys!

PS: whats reputation points and how do I get them? I wanted to included an image to give you guys an idea of my goal but it said I needed at least 10 of them.

Comment: Put the image link there, or here in comments and we will put it for you.

Comment: I ended up doing this pragmatically. How do I close this question? I'm not able to answer my own question...

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activity_Test"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp">


    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/image_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="@integer/num_columns"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_weight=".40"
        android:background="@color/grid_background"  />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/middle"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".20">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/home"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/battle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/begin"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".40">


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/test_bt_pick_pilot"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/test_bt_pick_pilot"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/test_bt_pick_pilot"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/test_bt_pick_pilot"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/test_bt_pick_pilot"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```